# How to test subscribe section of an observable in angular

Tags: angular

I have a method which looks like this -

```
downloadFile(): void {
    this.isDownloading = true;
    if (this.monthSelected) {
      this.accountGateway.getExport(
        this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id,
        this.monthSelected
      ).subscribe(data => {
        this.exportService.exportData(data);
        this.isDownloading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

I am trying to test it and wrote the below test. The problem is I am unable to figure as how can I test the subscribe section here like service getting called etc. I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
it("data download test", fakeAsync(() => {
      component.monthSelected = "Jan";
      const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#download-btn');
      button .click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(
        stubAccountGateway.getExport
      ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        stubRoute.snapshot.params.id,
        component.monthSelected
      );

      tick(1);

      // fails at this line
      expect(spyExportService.exportData).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.isDownloading).toBeFalse();
    }));
```

If I put a console in subscribe, it never prints. What am I doing wrong here? I tried with/without `fakeAsync` as well as suggested by some. I want to spy and assert that the service in subscribe is actually called.

Following is the stub implementation for  `stubAccountGateway.getExport`-

```
getExport(id: string, range: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return new Subject<Blob>();;
  }
```

Comment: Are you mocking a return valeu for accountGateway.getExport method? If it's not returning any observable the tick function won't run the subscribe, because there is no data

Comment: @FelipeBonfante, i added that detail in my question now, could you please take a look.

Comment: @FelipeBonfante, that indeed seem to be the case. I updated `return new Subject<Blob>();` to `return of(1, 2, 3);` and that seems to work as you suggested. Thanks a bunch mate. Will see if I could modify that like this one.

Comment: Nice! Did this solve your problem and answered your question? If yes, would you mind if I promote this comment to answer of your question?

Comment: @FelipeBonfante yes of course, would love to !! Thanks a bunch !!

Comment: Thank you @infinite! Nice It solved your problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mocking a return value for `accountGateway.getExport` method? If it's not returning any observable the tick function won't run the subscribe, because there is no data.

You need to mock the getExport method from accountGateway to return an observable like:

```
Observable.of(data)
```

This cold observable will emit the data and your subscribe will be called.

The subject itself do not emit data until the method next is called